# Xcode 13 - A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native

I'm trying to install the app into my real device "iOS 15.0.1"

In Xcode, the Automatically manage signing disabled

I added a provisioning profile from the developer site, and here is a screenshot that’s proving it's good.

This issue just appears when I disable the automatically managing signing.

[image: xcode]

```
Unable to install "App"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620395
User Info: {
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620395
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 487925;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008015)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000013ffd5316 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000014001384a __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010d532ed4 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x0000000140013594 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1420
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000013fcb6b4e __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.292 + 3508
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010d666c37 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010d6683a3 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 931
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff201e7623 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff201e8806 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff201ee5ea _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 606
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff201ef0ad _dispatch_lane_invoke + 366
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff201f8c0d _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 811
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff2038f45d _pthread_wqthread + 314
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff2038e42f start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--

System Information

macOS Version 11.6 (Build 20G165)
Xcode 13.0 (19234) (Build 13A233)
Timestamp: 2021-10-10T14:53:25+03:00
```

Comment: "and here is a screenshot that’s proving it's good" Actually the screenshot proves just the opposite. You've made the provisioning profile incorrectly if your goal is to run the app on your device.

Comment: @matt hey! I think if not appears any error in Xcode it will work too for running on my device and app store stuff, what should I add for It to work on my device too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that automatic signing works, the best course is to use it, since you clearly don't know how to make a provisioning profile manually. It's a little hard to understand why you would reject this convenient approach.

But if you *do* insist on making a provisioning profile manually, then the problem is simply that you've done it incorrectly. You have made a *distribution* certificate. You never use a distribution certificate except for one purpose: to export from an archive.

If your goal is to build and run the app on your device directly from Xcode, you need a *development* certificate and a *development* provisioning profile. The development certificate needs to be stored correctly in your computer's keychain. Make sure that you have registered your device at the member center, as well as your app of course, and that you include both of them along with the development certificate in the profile. To get started, go to Certificates at the developer member center, click the Plus button, ask for an *Apple Development* certificate, click Continue, and follow the instructions that you're given.

On the other hand, if you have been able to distribute the app to App Store Connect and your goal is to experiment with that version of the built app, then just use TestFlight to distribute the app to yourself from App Store Connect.

Comment: Thanks, @matt, you're right, after added Development Profiles it running on my device well. I just disable the automatically singing for CI/CD tool required that, and have a confused about Distribution/Development.

Comment: How did you add Development Profiles and where ? @OliverD

Comment: @RohitSingh just created it in the `Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles` page, then in the Xcode, I downloaded it `preferences => Accounts => choose team => Download manual profiles`, you will see it in the list of provisioning profiles